# Apply scale to a bullet colision body

Tags: mesh, ogre3d, bulletphysics

I'm using bulletphysics with ogre3d. to make them share the same vertex data i used this:
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/BulletMeshStrider
Now i have the following problem:
The actual Mesh data is apparently  shared correctly, but Ogre also has rotation, scale and position, which are managed by nodes. Rotation and Position weren't really a Problem but im kinda stuck on scale. So is there a way to scale a Bullet Collsion object?

Answer (score 1):

You're lucky I want to do the same in the near future. My research so far:

You need to use:
btScaledBvhTriangleMeshShape
http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtScaledBvhTriangleMeshShape.html

It wraps a btBvhTriangleMeshShape by use a different scale for the vertices. So you need a new collision object for every scale that you want to use.

Comment: scale has so many things to it.. like the ccd, the mass (if you scale by 0.5f, the mass will be 1/8), it would be cool if they added that ready to scale a physics without we having to deal with it manually